# Opening new UWP app using app-protocol from Startup application

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I can start an application using app-protocol feature in windows 10 and universal windows application.
To do that first i declare a protocol in **Package.appxmanifest** file in application B then from my main application which call application A, run this code to run application B :

```
var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("MyApplicationProtocolName:"));
```

But i face a problem, when main application is startup, i cannot lunch application B, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that declaring the protocol itself is not enough for the application to respond to it. You also need to implement the protocol activation in app B:

```
public partial class App
{
   protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
      {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                rootFrame = new Frame();
                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }
            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
            }
            Window.Current.Activate();
      }
   }
}
```

The initialization you need to perform in `OnActivated` will probably be similar to `OnLaunched` in case the app is not yet launched. In case the app is already running, you don't need to do anything special, it will just come to the foreground. In case it is not running, you have to create the main `Frame`, initialize the `Window.Current.Content` and then do `Window.Current.Activate()` to activate the app.

Comment: similar steps in c++/WinRT but app stuck at splash screen any suggestion ?

Comment: You need to make sure the `Window` is activated. You can also debug the app activation - https://blog.mzikmund.com/2019/03/debugging-uwp-app-lifecycle/ - that might help uncover the issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the example code from Microsoft on this subject. 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AssociationLaunching

See also: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-app-with-uri